# Entity Framework eager loading entity list within entity list

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, eager-loading

I've encountered a problem: I have a table that has a reference to another table, that has a list of references to another table, which has another list of references, and I want to eager load all of this.

Basically, the idea is:

```
public class User {
     public ClassL1 l1 { get; set; }
}

ClassL1 {
    public List<ClassL2> l2 { get; set; }
}

ClassL2 {
    public List<ClassL3> l3 { get; set; }
}

ClassL3 {
    //some basic string or int values
}
```

And currently, I'm trying to load it with something like this, but to no avail:

```
user = context.Users
  .Where(u => u.UserName == model.Username)
  .Include(u => u.l1)
  .ThenInclude(l1 => l1.l2)
  .ThenInclude(l2List => l2List.Select(l2Single => l2Single.l3))//This doesn't work
  //.Include(u => u.l1.l2.Select(l2Single => l2Single.l3)) //Neither does this
  .First();
```

How am I supposed to load a list of lists, if select isn't working? Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:
Well, since there apparently is an open bug on this, I went with a stupid fix, and made it work like this:

```
user = context.Users
  .Where(u => u.UserName == model.Username)
  .Include(u => u.l1)
  .ThenInclude(l1 => l1.l2)
  .First();
for (int i = 0; i < user.l1.l2.Count; i++) 
{
  user.l1.l2[i].l3 = context.l3DB
    .Where(p => p.l2.Id == user.l1.l2[i].Id)
    .ToList();
}
```

And for this to work, I added references up(to parents) inside the classes.
for example:

```
public class ClassL2 {
    public List<ClassL3> l3 { get; set; }
    public ClassL1 l1 { get; set; }//reference to parent
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
user = (from usr in context.Users
        where usr.UserName == model.Username
        select new
        {
            usr,
            usr.l1,
            l2List = from l2 in usr.l1.l2
                    select new
                    {
                        l2,
                        l2.l3
                    }
        }).AsEnumerable().Select(m => m.usr).First();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. I get an error:

"No coercion operator is defined between types 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable'1[ClassL3]' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[ClassL3]'."

Comment: Maybe this is an issue with your mappings. Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final"

I thought so too, but I can't find a way to fix it, had one prop named the same as it's classname, changed that, but the error persisted. I could upload the code snippets concerning this problem if that would be of any help.

Comment: Well it looks like there was a bug in EF 7 rc1 with selecting list navigation properties (https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4246). Not sure if this is the same reason though. Maybe you ask the guys over there on Github. I use queries like the one I posted with EF 6.1.3 without problems, the only difference I can spot is that your properties are List<> and I usually use ICollection<>, but this should not be an issue.

Comment: Got it, will have to look into it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
user = context.Users
  .Where(u => u.UserName == model.Username)
  .Include(u => u.l1)
  .ThenInclude(l1 => l1.l2)
  .ThenInclude(l2 => l2.l3)
  .First();
```

Comment: This doesn't work, l2 is a list, I cannot access properties from there, since it's not a single element. That's where my problem is at, if it worked that easily, I wouldn't have a problem, but right now i have to select first.